# How to put URL in array and search through array for matching string?

Tags: php, arrays, string

I am trying to search through a URL for a matching string, but the below code snippet doesn't seem to work.

```
<?php

$url = "http://www.drudgereport.com";

$search = "a";
$file = file($url);

if (in_array($search,$file)) {
    echo "Success!";
} else {
    echo "Can't find word.";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are just searching for an occurrence of a string on the page, you can use

```
$str = file_get_contents($url);
if (strpos($str, $search) !== false) {
    echo 'Success!';
} else {
    echo 'Fail';
}
```

Comment: How would I go about looping through the entire contents of $str and counting the number of a's, for example?

Comment: @Matt, you don't need a loop as the entire page is loaded as a string into `$str`. To count occurrences of a string in another string, try `substr_count()` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php).

Answer (score 1):

`in_array()` checks if an array member is equal to your needle.

It is improbable many websites will have a line which is equal to `a` only.

Also, is [`allow_url_fopen`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) enabled?

Answer (score 1):

That code will only find a line that has the exact `$search` string (likely including whitespace). If you're parsing HTML, check PHP's [DOMDocument](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) classes. Or, you can use a regex to pull what you need.

Answer (score 0):

As @alex says, check is allow_url_fopen is enabled.
Also you can use [`strpos`](http://www.php.net/strpos) to search the string:

```
<?php

$url = "http://www.drudgereport.com";

$search = "a";
$file_content = file_get_contents($url);

if (strpos($file_content, $search) !== false) {
    echo "Success!";
} else {
    echo "Can't find word.";
}

?>
```